# iOS Swift - No module such as Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

This is my podfile:

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Grabit' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Grabit
  pod 'Firebase','>= 2.5.0'
```

I tried:

1. Correct podfile like above.
2. Open project by terminal
3. Clean and rebuild project.

I tried it many times but I still get the error:

```
no module such as Firebase
```

These are my version of Firebase:

- Installing Firebase 3.5.2 (was 3.5.2)
- Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.3.1)
- Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working perfectly for me:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

You don't need to set the version, by using just the name, you'll always get the latest version.

In Termin do `pod install`, then `pod update`.

Then completely clean your project with `[CMD]+[ALT]+[SHIFT]+[K]`.

Then clean with `[CMD]+[SHIFT]+[K]`.

Then close Xcode, start MyProject.xcworkspace (white icon) and build.

Answer (score 3):

Things to check when getting this message:

> no module such as Firebase

1. Does your Podfile file have `use frameworks!`? should look something like

   ```
   use_frameworks!

   target 'Project' do
     pod 'Firebase'
     pod 'Firebase/Auth'
     pod 'Firebase/Core'
     pod 'Firebase/Database'
   end

   target 'Project' do
     pod 'Firebase'
     pod 'Firebase/Auth'
     pod 'Firebase/Core'
     pod 'Firebase/Database'
   end
   ```

   - Notice that if you want the latest version of a pod, you don't need to specify the version
2. Do you open your project with `MyProject.xcworkspace` (white icon) file and not with `MyProject.xcodeproj` (blue icon)?
3. Close `Xcode` and run `pod install` or `pod update`. Then open the `MyProject.xcworkspace` and `build` the project

Answer (score 2):

Try Cleaning up the Project.
So far this works for me. Also I notice you're missing the "end"

```
target 'yourProjectname' do
platform :ios, '9.3'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete Derived Data,Try Cleaning the Project and then Build, it will work then.